# Ssm agent is always installed only on the first windows instance created from ASG (Auto scaling group)

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-ami, aws-ssm

[AWS CLOUD]
I'm increasing my instances from auto scaling group but always only my first instance has ssm agent installed. My first instance created was connectable using the session manager but the other instances were not.

My AMI is generated from a windows instance that has ssm agent installed on it. My ASG also uses this AMI.

My wish is that every instance created from ASG has ssm agent installed and can be connected using session manager

I don't understand where the problem lies. Please help me
Thanks a lot

Comment: If the instances were created from the same AMI which had SSM installed, then all instances will have SSM installed. Have you actually logged in the servers to verify your claim?

Comment: I can't logged in to server because my instance doesn't have public ip address. In menu fleet manager of system manager service, i only see one instance to connect via ssm. @Paolo

Comment: Create an instance with a public ip from the AMI and check then